# Using iframes to add dynamic content to statically cached pages

Tags: wordpress, caching, iframe

I have a wordpress based site which makes use of a full page caching system. Problem is that I need to add dynamic content for logged in users. Right now I'm keeping the caching enabled for non-logged users and disabled for the logged ones via cookie check.

Would inserting the dynamic content in an iframe be an acceptable solution to extend the full page caching to all the users? Or any better ways?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to pull in the dynamic contents via AJAX. Of course your page will not be accessible without Javascript, but that may or may not be an issue.